# Ng-options to show name but record id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model, `$scope.beer`, and I want the user to be able to select from a list of breweries (`$scope.breweries`) to which that beer belongs. However, I want to display the *names* of the beer but have the model record the *id* of the brewery so that I can reference it in the database.

So far I have something like this:

```
<select name="brewery" ng-model="beer.brewery" ng-options="breweries.id as breweries.name for brew in breweries"></select>
```

However, my `<options>` element is printing undefined for the name. Am I using `ng-options` incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify ngOptions part to use `brew.id` and `brew.name`:

```
ng-options="brew.id as brew.name for brew in breweries"
```

since you have `brew` as an iteration item.